# Conditions five parameters have to satisfy to make matrix $A$ diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ a & -1 & 0 & 0 \\\ b & d & 1 & 0 \\\ c & e & f & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Its eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$. Both are double roots. Discuss the conditions $a,b,c,d,e,f$ must satisfy to make matrix $A$ diagonalizable.

Well, I hesitate in this exercise because when I try to get its eigenvectors, particularly the ones related to $\lambda = 1$ and I arrive to something like this

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ a & -2 & 0 & 0 \\\ b & d & 0 & 0 \\\ c & e & f & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

which multiplied by the column vector $(x;y;z;t)$ must result $(0;0;0;0)$. The solutions I obtain are $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$ and $t = \mu $(parameter), so the dimension of the subspace $V_{1}$ is $1$. As the multiplicity of 1 was 2, and this is not the dimension of the subspace, the matrix can't be diagonalized.

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The equations I have for that eigenspace are $-2x = 0 \rightarrow x = 0, ax-2y = 0 \rightarrow y = 0, bx + dy = 0, cx + ey + fz = 0 \rightarrow z = 0$. If x and y are 0, z necessarily has to be 0, unless there was a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: Note that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, which means the kernel of $(A-\lambda I)$ must have 2 linearly independent eigenvectors in your case.

Comment: The eigenspace associated with $1$ has dimension $1$ **if** $f \neq 0$. So according to your work, one of the required conditions is that $f  = 0$.

Comment: So, the main solution of this problem is that all the parameters have to be 0, right?

Comment: @galgarabel it turns out that only $a$ and $f$ need to be zero, and the rest can be freely chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\in M_n(K)$ where $K$ is a field. We will assume that  the characteristic polynomial of $A$ splits into linear factors over $K$ , which is an obvious necessary condition for diagonalizability.

Let $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_r\in K$ the distinct eigenvalues of $A$.

Then it is well-known that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $K^n=\bigoplus_i \ker(A-\lambda_i I_n)$.
It is not difficult to deduce the following:

**Theorem.** Assume that  the characteristic polynomial of $A$ splits into linear factors over $K$ .
Let $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_r$ the distinct eigenvalues of $A$. Then $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\prod_i(X-\lambda_i)$ annihilates $A$.

This gives you a criterion which avoid explicit computations of eigenspaces.

In your case, the eigenvalues of $A$ are  $1$ and $-1$, so $A$ will be diagonalizable if and only if $A^2=I_4$.

Now, $A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr -2a & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr ad & 0 & 1 & 0 \cr ae+bf & df & 2f & 1\end{pmatrix}.$

We easily deduce that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $a=0$ and $f=0.$